# Is it possible to mark figures from a video clip and crossfade them with computer graphics?

Tags: animation, video

I am trying to replace people in a video clip (real scenes) with an animated character (e.g. turn people in the video robots) that follow the movements of the people.
I know that it is possible to track a point in my footage and then blend it with an image. Is it also possible, when there is movement in the video, to crossfade to an appropriately animated computer graphic?
Thanks for your answers in advance!

Greetings Joe

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please [edit] your question and try to narrow your question some. The term *computer graphics* is extremely broad, as this site is for questions about blender, it's use and workflows. Please see the [tour]. Blender can do much of this, but your question should be clear of what your goal is, and must be on topic so that it can be answered.

Comment: I guess Blender is not quite the software to do it. Try dedicated video editors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers!
I was hoping Blender could give me some help in syncing character movements with the movements of the actors in the video.

Comment: you have two options that apply to basically all software - if it is replacement with a bigger object like iron man suit or something like that and there is nothing obstructing it you can just overlay the animation over the video. but if you want to replace with a similar sized or smaller object you have to mask out the character and replace it with a background image, and overlay on that. this is if you have a non moving shot. otherwise specify so in your question because that is more difficult because you need to 3d camera track and recreate the scene

Comment: @j-block Thank you for your answer!
I see now rather the workflow of the whole thing. I think I will introduce a freeze into the real video and then do the crossfade. This is probably easier and also better in the result.
Thanks again to all!

Comment: sure! if you do a freeze probably don't just stop out of nowhere instead depending on the software this might be easy or hard - but retime the end right before you cut and make it slow down until the freeze frame preferably with a ease out kind of curve

Comment: Again a good advice ! Thanks a lot! I'll try that.